# Add an "Export to Excel" button to a webpage to export gridview to excel in webapplication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, export-to-excel

i built a patient management software for a clinic and i need to export patiet list from ASP.net grid view to excel file

my question is:

Is there a way to export gridview to excel 
i am using vb.net and visual web developer 2010

i store datasource from advanced search page into a session and redirect to result page
here is the code of result page

```
Partial Class Sresults
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    GridView1.DataSource = Session("dsource")
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub Backbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Backbtn.Click
    Session("dsource") = ""
    Response.Redirect("searchme.aspx")

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    Response.Write(GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString + " Records")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code on the button click

```
// Get DataTable that DataGrid is bound to.
var dataTable = (DataTable)dataGrid.DataSource;

// Create new ExcelFile.
var ef = new ExcelFile();
// Add new worksheet to the file.
var ws = ef.Worksheets.Add(dataTable.TableName);
// Insert the data from DataTable to the worksheet starting at cell "A1".
ws.InsertDataTable(dataTable, "A1", true);

// Stream file to browser.
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Employee.xls");
ef.SaveXls(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

Comment: do i need to import microsoft interop name spaces? i cant find it in visual web developer express installation!!

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add the following to the page directive to avoid runtime error

```
 EnableEventValidation ="false"
```

---

add gridview to aspx page
the session "dsource" is passing the datasource from advanced search page containing the connection string and select command
then here is the code behind

---

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

public partial class csresults : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    gridview1.DataSource = Session["dsource"];
    gridview1.DataBind();




}


  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}



protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Patients.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
    form.Controls.Add(gridview1);
    this.Controls.Add(form);
    form.RenderControl(htextw);
    Response.Write(stw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

}

Comment: What if it's a visual web part?