# export gridview to excel error

Tags: vb.net

dear all, i tried the code below to make the export to excel, but not working correctly
i used this thread
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397631/add-an-export-to-excel-button-to-a-webpage-to-export-gridview-to-excel-in-webap/4401856#4401856)

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm(); 
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Patients.xls"; 
Response.ClearContent(); 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment); 
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"; 
StringWriter stw = new StringWriter(); 
HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw); 
form.Controls.Add(gridview1); 
this.Controls.Add(form); 
form.RenderControl(htextw); 
Response.Write(stw.ToString()); 
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try add to the aspx page directive

```
EnableEventValidation ="false"
```