# Creating Excel report form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to create an Excel report from VB.net in different ways and each one has a problem of its own. The most recent way I tried was to use ActiveX com. I tried different codes online and they all ended up with the following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I checked the error online and tried all solutions but I still get the same error on the following line:

```
Dim xlObject As New Excel.Application()
```

or similar line in different page:

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application =  New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

The program does not move to the next line and it means there is something wrong there.

Things I have done so far are:

1- I added references for  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library

2- I added Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop at the top of my code

3- I took care of objects created after the program finished working with them either using Try...Catch...Finally or without it. I used  xlObject.Workbooks.Close() and xlObject.Quit() and Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject for workbook, worksheet and range objects.

4- I tried assigning a workbook name (C:\Contracts\Filename.xls or C:\Contracts\Filename.xlsx) or let the program to create one. I gave all permissions to NetWork Service, myself as the user, IIs_IUSRS to the folder containing the filename.xls.

5- I changed dcomcnfg/component Services/Computers/My Computer/DCOM Config/Microsoft Excel Application Properties/Security tab and added Network Service account with Local Launch and Local Activation Permissions and Local Access Permission. After a lot of trial and error ways, I also added the same permissions to the dcomcnfg/component Services/Computers/My Computer properties.

I even copied some of online codes to my page and tried them. I am working on Windows Server 2008 SP 1, 64-bit OS and MS Office Professional 2010 version 14.0 (64-bit) and view the page from localhost.

Here is the latest code I tried:

```html
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
'Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class TestExcel5
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Private Sub btnWrite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWrite.Click

        Dim Testmsg As String = ""
        Try
            Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()


            If xlApp Is Nothing Then
                AlertUserMsgBox("Excel is not properly installed!!")
                Testmsg = "Excel is not properly installed!!"
                Return
            End If

            Testmsg = "Passed creating the Excel object......"

            Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet 1 content"

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\Contracts\Excel5.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, _
             Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
            xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
            xlApp.Quit()

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
            releaseObject(xlApp)

            AlertUserMsgBox("Excel file created , you can find the file C:\Excel5.xls")
        Catch ex As Exception

            AlertUserMsgBox("Error in export: " & ex.Message & "   AND Testmsg=" & Testmsg)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try


    End Sub

    Public Sub AlertUserMsgBox(ByVal sMsg As String)

        Session("AddScriptName") = Session("AddScriptName") + 1

        Dim ScriptName As String = "ScriptName" & Session("AddScriptName")
        Dim ScriptStr = " alert(""" & sMsg & """); "

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), ScriptName, ScriptStr, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try this code in a winform application? I'm not familiar with the inheritance you're using. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397631/add-an-export-to-excel-button-to-a-webpage-to-export-gridview-to-excel-in-weba

Comment: I tried similar code in Winform and it worked but when I tried it in my VB.net code, it gave me the error.

Comment: I copied your code directly into a WinForm app and it worked perfectly. I didn't copy the "Inherits System.Web.UI.Page" part though. I imagine that's the difference. It's probably something security related.

Comment: Keith, I looked at the link you suggested. In fact, it was the first method I used to create the Excel file. But it is cumbersome. User needs to save or open the file and when either way is selected, it gives me some other errors related to Excel, even though it finally creates the Excel file!

Comment: The key tag you are missing in this post is [asp.net].

Comment: Does the server have Excel installed on it, I would guess it does not.

Comment: In .aspx.vb files, I can not remove the System.Web.UI.Page and it gives other errors. That's why I tried to call a .vb class from my .aspx.vb file but still it hangs on the Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
line! any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, server has Excel with extension .xlsx and it can open .xls files with an extra msg.

Comment: Steve, how can I add a new tag to this question?

Comment: Click the edit button under your post and then add the tag to the tags section.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
Private Sub btnExportToExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExportToExcel.Click

    Dim StartDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim EndDate As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim worker = selectedWorker.FullName


    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    For i = 0 To dgvAppPlatite.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To dgvAppPlatite.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To dgvAppPlatite.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = dgvAppPlatite.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = dgvAppPlatite(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
    Next

    'Freeze top Row .. dar inca nu-mi merge
    xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Dim firstRow As Range = DirectCast(xlWorkSheet.Rows(1), Excel.Range)
    firstRow.Activate()
    firstRow.Select()
    'firstRow.AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, True)

    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Incasari : " & Label5.Text & " si comision : " & Label6.Text

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\Docs\Rapoarte\" & worker & " " & StartDate & " " & EndDate & ".xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("D:\Docs\Rapoarte\" & worker & " " & StartDate & " " & EndDate & ".xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code and got the same error msg plus some other line as follows:
Exception Details: ...To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
Same error! Now when I try to add the ASP.NET account, it doesn't appear in the list.

Comment: Then your problem came from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version .. 32-bit / 64 bit and also check on localhost what office driver do you have .. and check if you have rights to create file in your path ..

Comment: CristiC777,what could be wrong with my Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version? It does not have 32-bit or 64-bit version. As I mentioned in my question, my MS Office Professional 2010 version 14.0 is 64-bit and my Excel file has all rights.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Open XML SDK method to create an Excel file and I am not going back to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel anymore because of errors I could not figure out.